# Determine the dimensions of the kernel and image for the following function

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Function]

Hi,

in the above example I am not sure how to interpret the question, however I think the F means that I am working within Mod 7. If this is corrrect, how do I need to alter my approach to finding the image and kernel as has been done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236541/image-and-kernel-of-a-matrix-transformation)?

Also, does the dimension simply refer to the number of vectors in the final solution?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, proceed as in this similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702014/finding-the-kernel-and-image-of-a-linear-transformation-over-the-field-bbb-z-2). The field in your case is $F=\mathbb{F}_7$ with $7$ elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is exactly as in $\mathbf R$ or n $\mathbf C$ , except you're calculating in the field $\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z$. So perform *row reduction* to obtain the rank of the matrix, then use the *rank-nullity theorem* to obtain the dimension of the kernel.

We first need to have a pivot equal to $1$ for easier calculations. Knowing that $2^{-1}=4$,we multiply the first row by $4$ and obtain:
\begin{align}
&\begin{pmatrix}
2&3&0&4\\3&1&4&2\\5&4&1&0
\end{pmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
1&5&0&2\\3&1&4&2\\5&4&1&0
\end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow[R_3\leftarrow R_3-5R_1]{R_2\leftarrow R_2-3R_1}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&5&0&2\\0&0&4&3\\0&0&1&4
\end{pmatrix}\\
\xrightarrow{R_2\leftrightarrow R_3}
&\begin{pmatrix}
1&5&0&2\\0&0&1&4\\0&0&4&3\end{pmatrix}
\xrightarrow{R_3\leftarrow R_3-4R_2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&5&0&2\\0&0&1&4\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Thus the matrix has rank (= dimension of the image) $\,\color{red}3$. By the rank-nullity theorem, the kernel has dimension $4-3=\color{red}1$.